# How to move/animate CGRects

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having trouble moving CGRects around. I'm trying to make a breakout game. In my drawView file, I have written code in the drawRect function by removing the comments.
I end my drawRect function with this `moveBall(&_ball, &_context, rect);`

`moveball()` is declared/implemented in my viewController.h/viewController.m.

I'm not sure how to then move/animate the ball once it is in my controller. I have the following code:

```
void moveBall(CGRect *ball, CGContextRef *context, CGRect rect) 
{
    CGFloat velX = 1;
    CGFloat velY = 1;

    while (ball->origin.x + CGRectGetWidth(*ball) < CGRectGetWidth(rect))
    {
        CGContextClearRect(*context, *ball);
        *ball = CGRectOffset(*ball, velX, velY);
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(*context, *ball);
    }
};
```

What happens is that the ball is "moved" to a different place, not animated there. The problem is that the while loop is implemented and the final result is displayed. I want the while loop to run after the drawing is done.

Can anyone guide me to make the ball move?

Comment: As an aside, did you consider using SpriteKit or Cocos2d rather that UIKit?  You might actually get something you can play.  The issue with UIKit is that it's not designed for this and implementing a game loop is somewhat advanced.

Comment: The problem is that I am developing for the iPhone for the first time. I did C before, so I am naturally doing low level programming. Hence, I am not very aware of using spritekit. So, basic question, is it possible to use the current graphics that I have drawn with SpriteKit? Can i wrap them in?

Answer (score 2):

Trying to make animations inside the `drawRect` method using CoreGraphics framework is exercise in futility.

For animations you should use other frameworks/technologies intended for that.

- Standard apps - Core Animation
- Games - SpriteKit, OpenGL ES, Metal, cocos2D,  Unity3D,

Comment: `drawRect` should not be used for animations.

Comment: Isn't it exactly what I said?